# Best use of RAM for multiple SQL instances?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016

I have a new Windows Server 2016 box with 32GB of RAM, it will be used for dev testing by one or two users max.
There will be occasional use of VM/Hyper-V instances and a couple of IIS test sites running from time to time.

I also need to install *all* versions of SQL Server from 2008 through to 2016.
These will each have many databases attached but very few will actually be active at a time unless testing calls for it.

Assuming there is no practical issue with installing several different SQL Server installations on the same box, what options do I have to configure the best use of RAM?
I know that on a standard installation, SQL will try to hog all available RAM but I want to try to avoid this leaving around 12GB for other services and allocate a maximum of 24GB for *ALL* the SQL instances to share equally without fighting with each other over resources.

Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: To add another voice, I 100% agree with what TomTom said below. Do not run any other workloads directly on the Hyper-V host.

Comment: Not sure I understand?  I only have 2 or 3 VM's I need to run once or twice a month.  Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Running VMs is fine. What you should avoid is running anything else on the host (the bare-metal OS) than just the Hyper-V role. For instance, keep all of your SQL Server instances in VMs.

Comment: Ok but why?  Whats wrong with running SQL on the bare-metal, are you referring to the RAM allocation or something else?

Comment: See my answer here. This answer was for KVM, but it apples to any virtualization solution. http://serverfault.com/a/837079/20815

Comment: If you read MS documentation, even they will recommend the same.

Answer (score 1):

> There will be occasional use of VM/Hyper-V instances and a couple of IIS test 
>   sites running from time to time.

Never. Do. That. Install Hyper-V run everything in Hyper-V instances. Do not run load on the "physical" machine.

> Assuming there is no practical issue with installing several different SQL 
>   Server installations on the same box

Not totally sure, mostly because of your large selection. I keep a separate VM for every generation - easier to get rid of them this way.

> Is there a good way to achieve this?

Back to the start. Dump SQL Server in a VM, assign 24gb, finished. SQL Servers, running alone in the VM, will never use more memory.

COnsider upgrading RAM - 32gb is quite low for a development all kind of stuff server in days where workstation motherboards can go up to 64gb.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider the VM idea, but there might be licensing issues and time to create, and maintain each separate OS.
Also, presumably a large amount of the allocated RAM will be taken up by the OS rather than fully used by SQL.

Comment: There is no licensing issue, particularly not for development. WHat you are unaware of is that if you install Hyper-V the ROOT partition always has priority. RAM, CPU - if the root partition needs it, the VM's starve. Which is why "nothing on the host" is the rule on a virtualization system.

Comment: Aha! I see.  Great advice.  Ok so what if I don't install Hyper-V at all, what advice would you give for the SQL instances ?

Comment: Getting real. Seriously. Not joking. FOr anything that is a development system I would not forego the power and flexiblity of a virtualization layer, ever. For production, you can regularly plan load - for development things change fast.